# How does typeof globalThis work in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am reading through the `@types` TypeScript definitions repo, and looking at things like this for `@types/node`:

```
declare var global: typeof globalThis;
```

How does this work? `globalThis` is dependent on the *runtime environment*, so how is it resolved at compile time? I am reading about the [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html), but I already knew about that and it doesn't offer any suggestions on how it's implemented. How does typescript implement the handling of `typeof`, for things like this `globalThis`?

Comment: `globalThis` is an object that represents the global `this`. This is by definition from the spec `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis`. In typescript `globalThis` will contain all globally defined values. `typeof` in type space is just an operator that TS implements that gives you the type of any variable, incuding `globalThis`

Answer (score 2):

This is defined by [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) in `tsconfig`. Changing `lib` you can declare the expected environment and typescript will allow these features.
You can use different values when you write code for browsers/NodeJS/WebWorker.
But typescript doesn't check this environment, because it's runtime and not compile time.